# Finding and removing periods

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm using a Google Sheets and trying to create a formula to remove a period and anything that comes before it in a cell. For example:

```
idontwantthis.iwantthis
```

I have used this in the past:

```
=(RIGHT(D2,FIND("whatever characters here",D2,1) - 1))
```

but the period "." is a wildcard. I have googled around for a few hours and still have nothing that works. Any insight would be awesome!

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use the backslash to escape the period character, so you have one of two options:

for regexextract to capture everything after the period, thus ignoring everything before it:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\.(.*)")
```

or regexreplace to replace everything including and before the period:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*\.)","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will split the result, using a "." as delimiter and show only the last column:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1;"."),1,2)
```

If there are more "." involved, then use this formula:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1;"."),1,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A formula is not necessarily required, simply Find (Edit > Find and Replace...):

```
.+\.
```

with nothing (leave Replace blank) and *Search using regular expressions* checked should work.